# Exclude namespace from FxCop code analysis

Tags: c#, namespaces, code-analysis, fxcop, suppressmessage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StyleCop/FxCop 10 - How do you properly suppress a message only on a namespace level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386902/stylecop-fxcop-10-how-do-you-properly-suppress-a-message-only-on-a-namespace-l)
>   [How do I suppress FxCop rule 'DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes' with SupressMessage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3683729/102937)

I have a namespace ABC.Schema which has some classes. Name of classes are using underscore. I am checking FxCop analysis. I want to suppress this rule for namespace level.

namespace ABC.Schema
{
...
}

I want to suppress FxCop message CA1707:IdentifiersShouldNotContainUnderscores.

Does anyone have idea about this.
Please give your view on this.

Comment: Same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3683729/102937

Comment: or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6386902/102937

Comment: Thank you for your reply, In other question they are looking for namespace only, but I am interested in class within that namespace.

Comment: Look at both questions I linked.

Comment: This is one of the interesting question, so please open this.

Comment: It's already answered by the other questions.  Please read them.

Comment: First Option : I have to go for every class and put attribute; Second Option : Put attributes for every type on namespace. Is there any optimize way to solve this ?

Comment: Then apply a Suppression in the *"Project Suppression File"* (GlobalSuppression.cs).  See here: http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=30

Comment: Using this file I can keep suppress attribute, but not suppressing complete namespace. Please see the question. it is very different than existing one.

Comment: The [blog post I linked](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=30) describes **three different ways** of doing it.  You're saying that none of those three ways meets your need?